# Using application's internal cache while working with Cassandra

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra

As I've been working with traditional relational database for a long time, moving to nosql, especially Cassandra, is a big change. I ussually design my application so that everything in the database are loaded into application's internal caches on startup and if there is any update to a database's table, its corresponding cache is updated as well. For example, if I have a table `Student`, on startup, all data in that table is loaded into `StudentCache`, and when I want to insert/update/delete, I will call a service which updates both of them at the same time. The aim of my design is to prevent selecting directly from the database.

In Cassandra, as the idea is to build table containing all needed data so that join is unnencessary, I wonder if my favorite design is still useful, or is it more effective to query data directly from the database (i.e. from one table) when required.

Comment: On a side note, saving a database in the application is quite a bad idea as your application's performance will be based on input.

Comment: Yep, it actually makes start-up take longer, however, it is the trade-off I have to make while working on application which does a lot of looking up. I believe it will be faster by storing them in a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your described usecase I'd say that querying data as you need it prevents storing of data you dont need, plus what if your dataset is 5Gb? Are you still going to load the entire dataset?

Maybe consider a design where you dont load all the data on startup, but load it as needed and then store it and check this store before querying again, *like what a cache does*!

Cassandra is built to scale, your design cant handle scaling, you'll reach a point where your dataset is too large. Based on that, you should think about a tradeoff. Lots of on-the-fly querying vs storing everything in the client. I would advise direct queries, but store data when you do carry out a query, dont discard it and then carry out the same query again!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to query the data directly as saving all the data to the application makes the applications performance based on the input. Now this might be a good thing if you know that the amount of data will never exceed your target machine's memory.

Should you however decide that this limit should change (higher!) you will be faced with a problem. Taking this approach will be fast when it comes down to searching (assuming you sort the result at start) but will pretty much kill maintainability.

The former favorite 'approach' is however still usefull should you choose for this.